# Clear cache in Webview on "CSS update"?

Tags: android, html, css, .htaccess, webview

My users are using android app in webview. Now whenever I make changes in CSS it doesn't reflect back on user's device as earlier CSS is stored in cache memory of app. Is there any way to bypass this and reflect fresh CSS? Is there any way we can control CSS update from Server? Something Like setting commands in .HTACCESS file or programmatically.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: I think the only solution is to reload entire webview content

Comment: is it possible to reload entire webview content by command from server side as in this case app is in hands of actual users.

Comment: I think it is can be done using push message (ie. FCM), after app receive push message, your app should reload the webview content

Comment: This is  for no cache `view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);`